# How to update docker image used in Gitlab.com CI

Tags: php, docker, gitlab

I have a project build in gitlab.com CI that uses [the `php:8.0` image on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/8.0/images/sha256-2227eb0a33c102b46cd918b4a7f7228ba917d161e63b37739cde3bf7e8c43113?context=explore), which I can see is up to date with PHP 8.0.13. However, when my CI runs on gitlab.com, it's using an outdated version that breaks my build:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
  - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v6.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v6.0.0].
  - symfony/event-dispatcher v6.0.0 requires php >=8.0.2 -> your PHP version (8.0.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

You can see here that it is using PHP 8.0.1 rather than any more recent version.

I'm not using the `php:8.0` image directly, but via the `edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php` image that uses the `php:8.0` image as its base image [in its dockerfile](https://github.com/edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php/blob/master/php/8.0/Dockerfile). I'm guessing that the problem is in here, as this package has not been updated for a while.

How can I get gitlab to use a more recent version of the image?

Comment: Can you please post your gitlab-ci.yml for the job in question so we can see how it's configured? Also, are you using self-hosted runners?

Comment: As you mentioned, the issue is that `edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php` hasn't been updated and republished with the upstream changes in `php:8.0`. Unfortunately, this problem can't be resolved post-build of that image -- the image `edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php` is simply outdated and must be updated. You can't deal with that after-the-fact in any practical way... Maybe install a new version of PHP inline in your job (I doubt this will work well)? You just need the upstream maintainer to update the image -- or fork it and update it yourself and publish your own image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own docker image based on the original [8.0 Dockerfile](https://github.com/edbizarro/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php/blob/master/php/8.0/Dockerfile)  from gitlab-ci-pipeline-php.

To do that just clone the git repository, create new Dockerfile and build it. You can push it to docker hub or you can use the Gitlab's docker registry to store your docker image and use it as base for your projects.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is that the image is outdated, and there's not much I can do about that other than create my own, which is *really* not something I want to do.

Fortunately I found a solution – a different image that is a drop-in replacement, and it works perfectly. So I updated my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to say:

```
image: lorisleiva/laravel-docker:8.0
```

and all tests are running and passing again.